# MYSQL Error when creating a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have the following MySQL trigger query :

```
CREATE
TRIGGER `after_insert_stock` AFTER INSERT 
ON `stock` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF NEW.deleted THEN
        SET @changetype = 'DELETE';
    ELSE
        SET @changetype = 'NEW';
    END IF;
            INSERT INTO stock_audit (stock_id, commodity_name,commodity_id,delivery_no,supplier_name,batch_no,expiry_date,units_per_pack,no_of_packs,total_quantity,buying_price,selling_price,remarks,available_quantity,user_id,changetype) VALUES (NEW.stock_id,NEW.commodity_name,NEW.commodity_id,NEW.delivery_no,NEW.supplier_name,NEW.batch_no,NEW.expiry_date,NEW.units_per_pack,NEW.total_quantity,NEW.buying_price,NEW.selling_price,NEW.remarks,NEW.available_quantity,NEW.user_id, @changetype);

END$$
```

When I run the Query I get the following MySQL error : Error

SQL query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert_stock` AFTER INSERT ON `stock_audit`
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN
IF NEW.deleted
THEN
SET @changetype = 'DELETE';
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Please can some one help solving the  problem?

Comment: Which line in above code is line 7?

Comment: P5Coder please view the following  :    SET @changetype = 'DELETE';

Comment: @user689017. is deleted a column in your table? conceptually is a little weird to have a changetype of DELETE in a INSERT trigger. :p

Answer (score 1):

You've missed [`DELIMITER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html) declaration:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
TRIGGER `after_insert_stock` AFTER INSERT 
ON `stock` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF NEW.deleted THEN
        SET @changetype = 'DELETE';
    ELSE
        SET @changetype = 'NEW';
    END IF;
            INSERT INTO stock_audit (stock_id, commodity_name,commodity_id,delivery_no,supplier_name,batch_no,expiry_date,units_per_pack,no_of_packs,total_quantity,buying_price,selling_price,remarks,available_quantity,user_id,changetype) VALUES (NEW.stock_id,NEW.commodity_name,NEW.commodity_id,NEW.delivery_no,NEW.supplier_name,NEW.batch_no,NEW.expiry_date,NEW.units_per_pack,NEW.total_quantity,NEW.buying_price,NEW.selling_price,NEW.remarks,NEW.available_quantity,NEW.user_id, @changetype);

END$$
```

Comment: After adding the DELIMITER $$ , I get the following error  : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON `stock`FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF NEW.deleted THEN SET @changetype = 'DELETE';ELSE' at line 1

Comment: In my case, all is working fine (i.e. I'm getting error _"Table 'db.stock' doesn't exist"_ and, thus, syntax is correct). Can you post [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_stock AFTER INSERT ON stock FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    DECLARE changetype varchar;
    IF NEW.deleted THEN
        SET changetype := 'DELETE';
    ELSE
        SET changetype := 'NEW';
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO stock_audit (stock_id, commodity_name,commodity_id,delivery_no,supplier_name,batch_no,expiry_date,units_per_pack,no_of_packs,total_quantity,buying_price,selling_price,remarks,available_quantity,user_id,changetype) VALUES (NEW.stock_id,NEW.commodity_name,NEW.commodity_id,NEW.delivery_no,NEW.supplier_name,NEW.batch_no,NEW.expiry_date,NEW.units_per_pack,NEW.total_quantity,NEW.buying_price,NEW.selling_price,NEW.remarks,NEW.available_quantity,NEW.user_id, :changetype);
  END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simplified query -

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert_stock`
AFTER INSERT 
ON `stock` 
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO
  stock_audit (stock_id, commodity_name,commodity_id,delivery_no,supplier_name,batch_no,expiry_date,units_per_pack,no_of_packs,total_quantity,buying_price,selling_price,remarks,available_quantity,user_id,changetype)
VALUES
  (NEW.stock_id,NEW.commodity_name,NEW.commodity_id,NEW.delivery_no,NEW.supplier_name,NEW.batch_no,NEW.expiry_date,NEW.units_per_pack,NEW.total_quantity,NEW.buying_price,NEW.selling_price,NEW.remarks,NEW.available_quantity,NEW.user_id, IF(NEW.deleted, 'DELETE', 'NEW'));
```